# Django3: change style of selection field in admin view?

Tags: django, django-admin

In my django project I have a project model with a many to many field for users, which can be added and removed. This works well, however, the selection field in the admin view is a bit inconvenient. Selection works by clicking on the usernames. To select multiple users CTRL has to be held. If you do that wrong all selections can be removed just by clicking on a certain item.

So, it is easy to loose the current selection with this tool. A better tool would be something that works like the user-groups and -rights window, with two separate panels, unselected and selected items.

My question is whether this tool:

[image]

can be replaced this tool:

[image]

So that users not joined the project are listed on the left and joined users are on the right?
Or vice versa.

And what is the name of the second widget?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.filter_horizontal

Comment: I wished the django docs had more images to illustrate the concepts. It hard to find what you are looking for if you know know the specific terms.

Answer (score 0):

In `admin.py` add `filter_horizontal` to the admin-class, for example:

```
class ProjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ("pk", "path", "slug", "created", "path_exists", "created_by")
    list_display = ("pk", "name", "path", "path_exists", "created_by", "created")

    filter_horizontal = ('users',)
```

This will display the second widget.